# Why do I get a TypeError? It don't think it has to

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    status=discord.Status.dnd
    await bot.change_presence(status=status)
    print("Successfully Logged in")
```

> TypeError: Client.change_presence() got an unexpected keyword argument 'status'

I expected to be fine.

Comment: Based on what did you expect it to be fine? Could you link to the documentation of whatever library you're using there? We can't possibly know what bot is and what methods it has

Comment: Are you sure `change_presence` method takes `status` as a keyword ? Could you please post the method signature ?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Presumably based on https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.change_presence which shows the `status` keyword argument.

Comment: @farch It's in the discord.py documentation.

Comment: Ah thanks! Could you check the documentation you're using matches the version of discord. Py you're using?